# Calling WCF service functions on a windows 8 mobile app

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to call functions that are on the WCF service from a windows 8 phone app, but the only options I get have Async and Completed at the end. e.g. CustLogin appears as CustLoginAsync and CustLoginCompleted.

When I use functions with Async they are interpreted as Void even though they are not void in the WCF service

isn't there a way to call these functions normally?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should get parameters from CustLoginCompleted method.

For example: e.Result...

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you generate service reference automatically with Visual Studio and async methods are generated automatically. You can disable this behavior in:
Add Service Reference -> Advanced -> Disable allow generation of async operations. If you don't need them then disable them. Otherwise you should read about how to receive a result from async operations in c#.

Comment: Hi Zbigniew, thanks for your reply but that option is disabled  on my visual studio i.e. I cant disable "generation of async operations". I am using VS2013.

Comment: If you are using .Net 4.5 + you can switch to use Task-based operations which allows you to receive data with async/await pattern instead of old-fashioned callback based pattern.